# nestjs Login sessions require session support

Tags: nestjs, passport.js

I'm using nestjs with passport to integrate github oauth2. Nestjs application always reports  "Login sessions require session support".

`Login sessions require session support. Did you forget to use "express-session" middleware?  "ExceptionsHandler"`

I searched on google but no help. Could anybody help on this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out the solution as below.

```js
import * as session from 'express-session';
import * as passport from 'passport';

  app.use(
    session({
      secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: { maxAge: 36000000 },
    }),
  );

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
```